# What module handles word+period within paragraph fill?

Tags: fill-paragraph, sentences, wrapping

I'm experienced with elisp, and I'm using emacs 24.5.

I want to modify how fill-paragraph works for a special application, and I'm trying to figure out which elisp code handles the case where a short word followed by a period always goes to the next line.

For example, assume that some text looks like this:

**Period at the end. And then blahblahblah and additional blahblahblah.**

This text gets filled as follows (assume fill-column is 30):

```
Period at the
end. And then blahblahblah and
additional blahblahblah.
```

Note that the word "end" gets moved to the next line, even though the text length hasn't reached the fill-column value.

I'm trying to find the elisp code that handles this, so I can write my own version of this which overrides this behavior. I want the result to look like this:

```
Period at the end. And then
blahblahblah and additional
blahblahblah.
```

Could anyone point me to the 24.5 elisp code which handles this case?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is called [`sentence-end-double-space`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sentences.html).

There is quite a bit of flexibility there, so I will not rehash the manual here.

Comment: OK. I see. That's actually a variable, not a function. But at least I know what to search for now. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. You should now close your question by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439).

Comment: OOPS! Forgot to click on the check mark. Done.